# Trying to index 1.5M records from mysql to Elasticsearch but I get a jdbc java heap Error. Out of memory

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, jdbc, kibana, logstash-configuration

I have a very huge table that needs to be indexed in to Elasticsearch. It contains over 1.5 Million unique records and log-stash gives me a jdbc java heap error because it is running out of memory. I need to index every single one of these records. I have tried the page page_size options on log-stash but I know if I actually selected the actual number of records as the page-size it will break. Is there a work around thing problem?

I managed to page-size 300,000 records so far. That's only a fraction of the total.

If I page-size the total number of rows it will break due to a jdbc java heap error. It runs out of memory.

Comment: Hey man, you need to lower the page size and look into persistent queuing (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/persistent-queues.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to give that a try and update you on how it fares out.

Comment: is increasing the logstash heap an option? It's set it jvm.options: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-setting-files.html

Comment: @mikeb It turns out there's an option to increase the heap size. However, it does also mention that it's dependent on the amount of RAM allocated to the server.(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html)

Comment: @Daniel you can increase the heap in both logstash and elasticsearch. From the error you described, the right place to start is logstash. The link in my previous comment points out where you can do that with logstash.